# if else statement for calculating bmr

Tags: javascript

I am working on a school project which involves calculating bmr, I keep getting reference error when I call this function.

```
<script>
function calbmr(){
        var height, weight, age;
        var gender;

        age = parseFloat(document.bmiform.age.value)
        height = parseFloat(document.bmiform.height.value);
        weight = parseFloat(document.bmiform.weight.value);

        if (document.getElementById('Male').checked) {
             gender = (66 + (9.6 * weight) + (1.8 * height) – (4.7 * age));
             alert(gender);
         }  


        else if (document.getElementById('Female').checked) {
                 gender = (655 + (13.7 * weight) + (5 * height) – (6.8 * age));
                 alert(gender);
        }

        else {

            alert("please select a gender");
        }
    }
</script>
```

But it returns result when I change the code to this it returns result

```
if (document.getElementById('Male').checked) {
             gender = "Male"
             alert(gender);
         }  


        else {
            if (document.getElementById('Female').checked) {
                 gender = "Female";
                 alert(gender);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two false `-` sign in your code:

```
if (document.getElementById('Male').checked) {
    gender = (66 + (9.6 * weight) + (1.8 * height) - (4.7 * age));
    //                                             ^
    alert(gender);
} else if (document.getElementById('Female').checked) {
    gender = (655 + (13.7 * weight) + (5 * height) - (6.8 * age));
    //                                             ^
    alert(gender);
}
```

Comment: but I want to minus 4.7 * age, did you mean that is not a minus sign? sorry about that, i'm new to javascript

Comment: yes, the sign, you have used is not a valid minus sign. just copy my code above with the right minus sign.

Comment: pleas he a look to your formula, it looks a bit twisted. source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harris%E2%80%93Benedict_equation)